# how to make it docker image for node application

Tags: docker, mean-stack

I have an one node application. An application is working in my system. Now I want to run same application in others environments/machine using docker. I am new to the Docker. Can u suggest any idea or link to run the application in all the environments using docker

Thanks in advance

Comment: these something called google and documentation!! if u had any problem with understanding some part that would be a suitable question to ask!

Comment: Could you give at least some information on the issue? If you cannot get started start with official nodejs & docker docs here for example https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

Comment: I go through docker file creation, samething is not working for me. I dont know how to know whether the node application is running in docker or not

Comment: What have you attempted so far? What errors are you running into? It sounds like you need to do some more research on Docker and Dockerizing nodejs apps before coming back here

Comment: (just guessing) but sounds like you're wanting something like this https://blog.soundly.me/posts/How%20to%20create%20a%20node%20app%20under%20Docker.html

Answer (score 0):

You have barely given any information about the application and what you are trying to achieve, so based on what you have given, I can briefly say what you should do.

First create the container by placing a `Dockerfile` in your (or outside) application's folder. You have to choose a base for your docker container and a great place to look for this, is in the [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/). An example base is the [alpine image](https://hub.docker.com/r/mhart/alpine-node/). You can also install all the dependencies of your application by using `RUN apk add --update --no-cache \` in the `Dockerfile` (if you use the alpine image that is) and last but not least, use a command or entrypoint as a starter of the container.

I would recommend you look at some guides on [how to dockerize a node application](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/), as there are plenty out there and from what you have given in your question, I doubt that someone would be able to help you more.